# Access to inherited variable in solidity to overwrite it

Tags: solidity

I want to override the following inherited function:

```js
function _setBaseURI(string memory baseURI) public override(ERC721Full, ERC721Metadata) {
    _baseURI = baseURI;
}
```

The problem is that I get an error

> Undeclared Identifier

with `_baseURI`.

The variable was implemented private. Is it for that reason that it cannot be overwritten? And if so, why can the function be?

My contract:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.0.0-beta.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.0.0-beta.0/contracts/drafts/Counters.sol";

contract GameItem is ERC721Full {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721Full("GameItem", "ITM") public {
    }

    function awardItem(address player, string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(player, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }
    
      function _setBaseURI(string memory baseURI) public override(ERC721Full, ERC721Metadata) {
        _baseURI = baseURI;
    }
}
```

The Heritage

```js
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "../../GSN/Context.sol";
import "./ERC721.sol";
import "./IERC721Metadata.sol";
import "../../introspection/ERC165.sol";

contract ERC721Metadata is Context, ERC165, ERC721, IERC721Metadata {
    // Token name
    string private _name;

    // Token symbol
    string private _symbol;

    // Base URI
    string private _baseURI;

    // Optional mapping for token URIs
    mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;

    /*
     *     bytes4(keccak256('name()')) == 0x06fdde03
     *     bytes4(keccak256('symbol()')) == 0x95d89b41
     *     bytes4(keccak256('tokenURI(uint256)')) == 0xc87b56dd
     *
     *     => 0x06fdde03 ^ 0x95d89b41 ^ 0xc87b56dd == 0x5b5e139f
     */
    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC721_METADATA = 0x5b5e139f;

    /**
     * @dev Constructor function
     */
    constructor (string memory name, string memory symbol) public {
        _name = name;
        _symbol = symbol;

        // register the supported interfaces to conform to ERC721 via ERC165
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC721_METADATA);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Gets the token name.
     * @return string representing the token name
     */
    function name() external view override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Gets the token symbol.
     * @return string representing the token symbol
     */
    function symbol() external view override returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the URI for a given token ID. May return an empty string.
     *
     * If the token's URI is non-empty and a base URI was set (via
     * {_setBaseURI}), it will be added to the token ID's URI as a prefix.
     *
     * Reverts if the token ID does not exist.
     */
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) external view override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");

        string memory _tokenURI = _tokenURIs[tokenId];

        // Even if there is a base URI, it is only appended to non-empty token-specific URIs
        if (bytes(_tokenURI).length == 0) {
            return "";
        } else {
            // abi.encodePacked is being used to concatenate strings
            return string(abi.encodePacked(_baseURI, _tokenURI));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal function to set the token URI for a given token.
     *
     * Reverts if the token ID does not exist.
     *
     * TIP: if all token IDs share a prefix (e.g. if your URIs look like
     * `http://api.myproject.com/token/<id>`), use {_setBaseURI} to store
     * it and save gas.
     */
    function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) internal virtual {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI set of nonexistent token");
        _tokenURIs[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal function to set the base URI for all token IDs. It is
     * automatically added as a prefix to the value returned in {tokenURI}.
     *
     * _Available since v2.5.0._
     */
    function _setBaseURI(string memory baseURI) internal virtual {
        _baseURI = baseURI;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Returns the base URI set via {_setBaseURI}. This will be
    * automatically added as a prefix in {tokenURI} to each token's URI, when
    * they are non-empty.
    *
    * _Available since v2.5.0._
    */
    function baseURI() external view returns (string memory) {
        return _baseURI;
    }


    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual override {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);

        if (to == address(0)) { // When burning tokens
            // Clear metadata (if any)
            if (bytes(_tokenURIs[tokenId]).length != 0) {
                delete _tokenURIs[tokenId];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a visibility issue.

If you want to access the `_baseURI` property in a derived contract, you need to make it at least `internal` (it's currently `private`).

Which also means copying a set of contracts locally so that you can update the `ERC721Metadata.sol` and import the updated version (and not the remote version) from the other contracts.

The `_setBaseURI()` function alone can be overridden because it's visible from your contract.

---

> *Private functions and state variables are only visible for the contract they are defined in and not in derived contracts.*

Cannot access private property in a derived contract.

Source of the quote: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters

Comment: `function _setBaseURI(string memory baseURI) internal override {
  
    }` Overwriting this function would have no effect.

In this case then you would have to import the two files. Because Metadata is inherited in ERC721Full. not?

Comment: @FernandoLópez Overriding (in `GameItem`) the function (defined in `ERC721Metadata`) would have an effect - you would be able to override the function (but not set the `_baseURI` property without changing its visibility first)... But as you're saying, you'd need to import the two files to be able to change the `_basURI` property visiblity (and to be able to access it in `GameItem`).